# How i check list of page enable/disable in magento using CLI?

Tags: magento2, page

I am new developer in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

So do you want to disable/enable the cms pages?

Go to Admin.

1. magento admin url/login
2. Left Navigation->Content->Pages (You can see the page list)
3. Select the page that you want to enable/disable
4. In the Action column, select the edit action.
5. You can see the "Enable Page" Yes or No.